# Qt/C++ pass static method's argument to class method

Tags: c++, qt, qtandroidextras

Is there a way to pass a static method's argument to a class method?
I've tried with QTimer this way:

```
QTimer g_timer;
QString g_arg;

void staticMethod(QString arg)
{
  g_arg = arg;
  g_timer.start(1); // It will expire after 1 millisecond and call timeout()
}

MyClass::MyClass()
{
  connect(&g_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MyClass::onTimerTimeout);

  this->moveToThread(&m_thread);
  m_thread.start();
}

MyClass::onTimerTimeout()
{
  emit argChanged(g_arg);
}
```

But I've got errors with threads because the staticMethod is called from a Java Activity, so the thread is not a QThread.

The errors are:

```
QObject::startTimer: QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread
```

if g_timer is not a pointer, or

```
QObject::startTimer: timers cannot be started from another thread
```

if g_timer is a pointer and I instantiate it in MyClass constructor

Any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: there is no class method with arguments in the code. What errors do you get?

Comment: Problem is caused by fact that you are using `QTimer` as a global variable. This is constructed before `QApplication` so `QTImer` do not see default event loop.

Comment: Also this line `this->moveToThread(&m_thread);` is very suspicious (there is not enogth context to say if it breaks anything).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific instance you can use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` to send the message over a cross-thread QueuedConnection:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&g_timer, "start", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(int, 1));
```

This will deliver an event to the owning thread from where the `start` method will be called, instead of the current (non-QT) thread.